# add an <a> element to Google Document using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to include a "properly formatted" `mailto:` link in a paragraph of text in my document:

```
"Please <a href="mailto:me@me.com">contact me</a> if you have any questions."
```

The only way I can think of doing this is with multiple Paragraphs and Styles, which I don't think would be an elegant solution. I was wondering if there was just some easier way of including an `<a>` tag directly in the document. The `Text` object has a `setLinkUrl()` method, but I'm not sure how to create a `Text` object! `var link = "my link text"` creates a `String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A working solution using the paragraph class,

```
var par1a = doc.appendParagraph("Please ");
var link = doc.appendParagraph("Contact me ").setLinkUrl("mailto:me@me.com");
link.merge();
var par1b = doc.appendParagraph("if you have any questions.");
par1b.merge();
```